# What type of operation I'm missing..?

Tags: android, android-layout

I read this Android Studio documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

Well the documentation is pretty obvious, to support different screens. 
Use match_parent, wrap_content, create layout-sw folders.. Hmm, eazy task.. Yep, I made 5 layout-sw300dp-700dp folders, every layout owns match-parent and wrap content characteristic.. But somehow my image isn't getting scaled and all I want to do is to scale the image in one of my LinearLayouts..

I know theres a lot of answer out there on the forum, but as you can see its not confusing for me, but I'm sure I'm missing something important to end the screen support..

Should I create different size images and place them in a drawable folder?

Because whenever I'm reviewing another layout file for example sw600dp the image isnt scaled there.. Even the layouts aren't getting scaled..

Should I configure every layout-sw folders? I mean to place bigger image, to resize layouts.

I need to fill up the LinearLayout with the image. Now there's white spaces on the left and right side of the LinearLayout

The code belongs to the RelativeLayout, which has match-parents aswell.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="This is random text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.39"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:gravity="fill">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. You mention wanting to scale an image, but your posted layout has no `<ImageView>` tags. You also spend a lot of time talking about different resource folders, but resource folders (even with `swNNNdp` qualifiers) don't automatically perform image scaling. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Should I create different size images and place them in a drawable folder?  Should I configure every layout-sw folders? I mean to place bigger image, to resize layouts? And it does have <imageView> tag, take a look at the bottom of the code

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. Please elaborate.

Comment: Well I'm trying to scale my image inside LinearLayout, I'm using android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" within my Image code, but this doesn't help either

Comment: Please see this help page for ways to improve your question so that I might be able to answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I need to fill up the LinearLayout with the image. Now there's white spaces on the left and right side of the LinearLayout

Comment: Maybe I should create the same image only with different size?

Comment: @Tadukas To scale any image that you are inserting into an ImageView use property `android:scaleType=YOUR_SCALING_MODE _GOES_HERE`